# Finding minimum value for a function in the defined range

Tags: python, scipy

I need to find the minimum value `Y` for some `X` in a given range. I am trying this with the `scipy` module.

The function that I want to find minimize is :

```
(x - 100) / 100
```

Here is what I have done:

```
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize

def f(x):
    Y = (x - 100) / 100
    return Y

min_result = minimize(f, 2, method="SLSQP", options = {'disp': False}, bounds=(0,101))
print("Minima found at: X = {}, Y = {}".format(min_result.x, min_result.fun))
```

When I run the above code, I get the following error:

```
IndexError: SLSQP Error: the length of bounds is not compatible with that of x0.
```

What could be the reason for this? I need to find the minimum value for `X` between 0 and 100.

Comment: try with `bounds=[(0,101)]`, bounds have to be sequence (i.e. a list or tuple) of tuples ``(min, max)``

Comment: @xdze2 Yes, it works. You can have this as an answer.

Comment: The minimum of `(x - 100) / 100` for `a <= x <= b` occurs at `x = a`, and the minimum value is `(a - 100)/100`.  Is that really the problem that you are trying to solve?

Comment: I think @Warren the idea was to experiment with a simple function (probably easily solvable by hand) and then proceed.

Comment: @Eypros, that's my guess too, but it would be better if the question made that clear.